# How to Generate a Wallet Address Using a Key Pair on the Client Side with EverSDK

Tags: blockchain

In **Venom Blockchain**, I am using eversdk library to generate the wallet key pair. I have successfully generated

```
const seedBuffer = await client.crypto.mnemonic_derive_sign_keys({ phrase: seed });
```

- Public Key
- Private Key
- Seed Phrase

and i have also generate the wallet address using same but on node side when i use on client side i am getting error.

**Invalid BOC: code BOC deserialization error: unknown BOC_TAG: 1008813135**

```
const everWalletAddress = `0:` + (await client.boc.get_boc_hash({ boc: stateInit })).hash;
    console.log('Address: ', everWalletAddress);
```

In short i want to generate wallet address on client side [React].